# How to feed data to a mobile app for a website

Tags: android, html, database-design

There are various websites (say LinkedIn) which have a corresponding mobile app.My question is - "How they feed data to their mobile apps?". Obviously they are not doing HTML scraping of their webpages, otherwise it would be really inefficient.

I am asking this because I have a website, and I am also going to develop an android app for that.So, do I have to design my website (like database) in a specific way to support mobile apps. (I mean, what are the preconditions do I take care of , while designing my website, in relation to the mobile apps)

Answer (score 4):

What you need is a web service. It sounds little complicated but actually its not! in normal websites when you visit a website you get HTML data. but in web service when you request for a data you get the data in xml or json. Then on client side you parse this data and show it as you like.

The most used method for sending data between web services and clients is called RESTful web service and it usually uses json. So after a request you get a .json file. I highly recommend you to use RESTful web service especially since you are a beginner.

As i said RESTful web services are famous so most frameworks support that! So if you are creating you website with this frameworks you don't have to code anything! they build the web service for you. If not there are plenty of code for any given language.

Another thing is since xml (and json) file are platform independent you only need one web service to handle all of the client (android, ios, windows, etc.). And there are sufficient tools and libraries in each platform to work with xml (json) files. Sending data to server is also the same, you send the data in xml format, service receive it and do what ever need to be done (for example stores the data in database)

Lastly the world of web services are a lot bigger. What i said was a highly simplified version to give you a whole idea! If you interested to learn more there are plenty of books you can read. Many people (including myself) think web services are the future of internet. Where different services each developed by different company work together to provide user with something great.